# Why do I need an Interface for Covariance (out Type)?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I just need to use the covariant `out` generic type modifier again. I had a class with a generic type and wanted to add an `out` but VS told me that this is only possible on interfaces.

But why can I use the `out` modifier only on an interface?

I helped myself in creating an interface copy of my class but this seems a little bit strange to me to only have an interface so I can use this modifier.

Comment: Mr. Lippert's classic (and correct) response would be "because no one has implemented yet", with of a follow up of "the cost doesn't justify the added value".

Comment: @DStanley: Though that is true, there are additional technical reasons here. If the class is not immutable then what are you going to do *safely* with a variant T?  If T is "in" then a field of type T cannot be read, and if T is "out" then a field of type T cannot be written; fields you can either not read or not write seem like useless features.  Covariance would be great for immutable classes, where all the fields are readonly; they could be written in the constructor. *That* is the point where my maxim about costs and values applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's extremely difficult to ensure that the class's definition is in fact covariant.  It is much easier for the compiler to ensure that the interface is in fact covariant.

With a class, simply having a field that uses the generic type instantly forces the generic argument to be invariant, because as far as the compiler can tell, the value can be both read and modified.  While it might be *possible* for classes to support variance, in practice the constraints that it would need to apply for developers to actually use it would be prohibitively difficult, much more so than simply creating a wrapping interface.

Let's consider a simple example:

```
public interface IWrapper<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
public class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T>
{
    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

**The class shown above is not covariant with respect to `T`** (until you cast it to the interface).  It accepts an input value of type `T` (through the constructor).  The interface is able to be covariant only because the constructor is not exposed through the interface.

Comment: The fact that the constructs a `T` shouldn't affect covariance, since constructor calls always act upon things whose exact type is specified.  Bigger issues arise with the behavior of static members.  I'm not sure how one could even define consistent semantics for those, much less implement them.

Comment: thanks, so an interface is not covariant if I have one method with a T param?

Comment: @JanS Correct.  Try it and see what the compiler says.